# Where did I go wrong with indexing? Or is it something else?

Tags: sql, mariadb, query-optimization

Please, help me optimize a single query for start.Story goes: I have a table called "temp", where statistics rows are inserted very frequently throughout the day (approximately 30 - 50 million rows inserted every day at irregular time patterns). Once every day (after midnight), my job is to select the 30-50 million rows, group and compute some data, and insert into "computed" table.

Since there are so many rows, I decided it would be best to run a query to select data in hourly periods, so I am running basically 24 select queries. The problem is, the query to select an hourly data is veeery slow. Talking about 90 seconds approximately.

First, some basic data. I am using MariaDB, and engine is InnoDB.Structure of the "temp" table is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
    id                  char(36)              NOT NULL default uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
    device              tinyint    unsigned   NOT NULL,
    country_code        varchar(2)            NOT NULL,
    canvas_id           bigint     unsigned   NOT NULL,
    paid_configured     int        unsigned   NOT NULL,
    paid_count          int        unsigned   NOT NULL,
    non_paid_configured int        unsigned   NOT NULL,
    non_paid_count      int        unsigned   NOT NULL,
    timestamp           timestamp             NOT NULL default current_timestamp() 

) engine = InnoDB;
```

And I have an index:

```
create index temp_composite_index on temp (
    timestamp,
    canvas_id,
    device,
    country_code
)
```

The query I am trying to optimize is:

```
    SELECT  canvas_id AS canvas_id,
            device AS device,
            country_code AS country_code,
            SUM(paid_configured) AS paid_configured_sum,
            SUM(paid_count) AS paid_count_sum,
            SUM(non_paid_configured) AS non_paid_configured_sum,
            SUM(non_paid_count) AS non_paid_count_sum
    FROM temp
    WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2023-12-02 12:00:00' AND '2023-12-02 12:59:59' 
    GROUP BY canvas_id, device, country_code;
```

Explain results are:

```
{
    "query_block": {
        "select_id": 1,
        "filesort": {
            "sort_key": "temp.canvas_id, temp.device, temp.country_code",
            "temporary_table": {
                "table": {
                    "table_name": "temp",
                    "access_type": "range",
                    "possible_keys": [
                        "temp_composite_index"
                    ],
                    "key": "temp_composite_index",
                    "key_length": "4",
                    "used_key_parts": [
                        "timestamp"
                    ],
                    "rows": 2609006,
                    "filtered": 100,
                    "index_condition": "temp.timestamp between '2023-12-10 12:00:00.000000' and '2023-12-10 12:59:59.000000'"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other data:

```
{
    "rows_total": 30000000,
    "rows_between_timestamps": 1249369,
    "unique_combinations": {
        "canvas_id": 20,
        "device": 2,
        "country_code": 4
    }
}
```

I have tried many index combinations and orders, and also have changed order of where and group by columns, but nothing seemed to work. If you need any other info feel free to ask. Thanks!

EDIT:

1. I am not familiar with the reason why is it decided to use UUID instead of BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT.
2. Yes, I always use current timestamp when I insert.
3. MariaDB version 10.6
4. It fits the pattern.

Comment: Show us your `EXPLAIN` results.

Comment: How many rows in the table? What percentage of the whole table is `timestamp BETWEEN '2023-12-02 12:00:00' AND '2023-12-02 12:59:59'` And how many unique combinations of `canvas_id, device, country_code`

Comment: @Charlieface Rows: 30,000,000 Number of timestamp between records: 1,249,369. Unique combinations of canvas_id is roughly 20, device 2 and country code 4.

Comment: @DomagojSamardžić Please edit your post instead of using comments

Comment: @Dai Sorry. Did it.

Comment: Why is your Primary Key a UUID rather than a BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT? When you INSERT rows, do you always insert the current timestamp? Please [edit] your question to explain.

Comment: Which MariaDB version? And fits the pattern of this [optimizer feature request MDEV-32870](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32870) I recently wrote.

Comment: @O.Jones edited

Comment: @danblack edited

Comment: Your index looks ideal for this query. The only idea that comes to mind is partitioning the table by day. Thus you'd only deal with one day's data from the start.

Comment: On a side note: I see that you are using a timestamp data type without milliseconds. In a query, however, I would not rely on this. Use `WHERE timestamp >= DATE '2023-12-02' AND timestamp < DATE '2023-12-03'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A few observations about this:

1. 90 seconds to summarize a couple of megarows from an active table is not ridiculously slow. There isn't weird SQL voodoo that can make it far faster.
2. It looks like your result set is reasonably small -- 160 rows for each hour, more or less.
3. You're doing historical reporting of a table that only gets INSERT operations at the latest time.
4. A `BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key is going to be more efficient than a `DEFAULT UUID()` primary key, if you can change it.
5. Using `BETWEEN` for date range filters isn't wise, because the end of the range is inclusive.  Use this, noting the `<` comparison operator.

   ```sql
   WHERE timestamp >= '2023-12-02 10:00' AND timestamp < '2023-12-02 11:00'
   ```

My suggestions.

1. Do the whole day's reporting in one query, rather than running a separate query for each hour. Something like this:

   ```sql
    SELECT  HOUR(timestamp) AS hour,
            canvas_id AS canvas_id,
            device AS device,
            country_code AS country_code,
            SUM(paid_configured) AS paid_configured_sum,
            SUM(paid_count) AS paid_count_sum,
            SUM(non_paid_configured) AS non_paid_configured_sum,
            SUM(non_paid_count) AS non_paid_count_sum
     FROM temp
    WHERE timestamp >= '2023-12-02'
      AND timestamp < '2023-12-02' + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
    GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp), canvas_id, device, country_code;
   ```

   It will, with the index you already have, be approximately the same amount of work as running 24 separate time-bounded queries.
2. Because you're doing historical reporting on an INSERT-only table you can set InnoDB's [transaction isolation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html) to a permissive level, to reduce contention between INSERT operations and your reporting. Give this SQL command before your reporting query. (Don't do this in databases with more complex transaction patterns unless you study up on what it does and convince your stakeholders it won't yield bogus results.)

   ```sql
   SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
   ```
3. You might consider using a so-called [covering index](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/compound-composite-indexes/#covering-indexlast_name-first_name-term), to allow your entire query to be satisfied by scanning the index sequentially. That will add SSD / HDD space to your table, but the tradeoff may be worthwhile if you have a critical need for doing this reporting query very fast.

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE temp
   DROP INDEX temp_composite_index,
   ADD INDEX temp_composite_index 
       (timestamp, canvas_id, device, country_code,
        paid_configured, paid_count, non_paid_configured, non_paid_count);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive and detailed response. I appreciate it. I took half of the day testing most of your suggestions, and allow me to refer to some of them. 

1.) I switched to BIGINT AUTOINCREMENT, and it showed no performance upgrade whatsoever. It probably has performance upgrade related to the multiple inserts throughout the day, but not to the select query. 
2.) BETWEEN is OK to use here if there are no significant performance upgrade, because I am trying to include end of the range too.
3.) I havent tried setting the transaction isolation level yet.

Comment: I discovered something: I get best efficiency by using either covering index either no index at all. Yes, they both work the same. I get 30 million grouped records (for entire day) in arround 27 seconds, and an hourly grouped record for cca 1.875s.

So, I decided to go with the no index option at all, since I am getting 30-50 million individual inserts per day.

My question to you is: How does the DBMS behave when, somewhere in the middle of the night, it is processing a SELECT of 27 seconds, and at the same time getting constant inserts?

Comment: Reducing SELECT / INSERT contention is the whole point of READ UNCOMMITTED. And, the DBMS handles BETWEEN and the range scan I suggested identically, except for the end of the range. Using BETWEEN on date stamp range scans is incorrect for the reason I explained. Next thing for you to learn about: clustered indexes.

Comment: And, using autoincrement in place of DEFAULT UUID() also helps reduce SELECT / INSERT contention: it's easier for the DBMS to be sure the PK is unique during each INSERT, which reduces locking.

Answer (score 0):

You have a range condition on the first index column (`timestamp`),
which makes it impossible to use the folowing index columns for anything but "covering".
And that means that all rows matching the range condition (like 1M to 3M)
have to be sorted in a temporary table to perform the GROUP BY operations.

A better index would support an equality condition on the date-hour part of the timestamp.
You can create such an index using virtual (generated) columns. Example:

```
alter table temp
  add column virtual_date date as (date(timestamp)),
  add column virtual_hour tinyint unsigned as (hour(timestamp)),
  add index idx_virtual_date_hour_sum (
    virtual_date,
    virtual_hour, 
    canvas_id, 
    device, 
    country_code
  );
```

Now you can change your `WHERE` clause to

```
WHERE virtual_date = '2023-12-02' AND virtual_hour = 12
```

and the *filesort* should be gone in the execution plan.

Farther optimisation would be to include al other columns in the index (make it covering),
so that the query can operate on that index.

```
alter table temp
  add column virtual_date date as (date(timestamp)),
  add column virtual_hour tinyint unsigned as (hour(timestamp)),
  add index idx_virtual_date_hour_cov (
    virtual_date,
    virtual_hour, 
    canvas_id, 
    device,
    country_code,
    paid_configured,
    paid_count,
    non_paid_configured,
    non_paid_count
  );
```

That would be the perfect index for the new query.

Don't forget that every index slows down writes. The bigger the index (more columns)
the more the overhead.

If this works well for a single hour you can also try a per-day query:

```
alter table temp
  add column virtual_date date as (date(timestamp)),
  add index idx_virtual_date_cov (
    virtual_date,
    canvas_id, 
    device,
    country_code,
    paid_configured,
    paid_count,
    non_paid_configured,
    non_paid_count
  );
```

And the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE virtual_date = '2023-12-02'
```

I would also have a look at [Partitioning](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/partitioning-overview/).
It could improve both - reads and writes, if you keep old data, but barely toutch it.